# Replacing the label with new label in python tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I wanted to replace the new label with an existing one in tkinter. But I am not able to do it. Below is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
def exact():

    choice = int(e.get())
    if choice == 1:
      Label1=Label(root,text="Cool").place(x=800,y=100)
    elif choice == 2:
       Label2 = Label(root,text="Cooler").place(x=800,y=100)
    elif choice == 3:
        Label3=Label(root,text="Coolest").place(x=800,y=100)
```

Comment: You're creating a new variable for each choice. Instead, reassign an existing variable.

Comment: Sure,But how do I replace the label

Comment: Why replace the label widget instead of replacing just the text on the label? Research the `configure` method.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are trying to do but I think that this: `<tkinter.Label>.config(text="new text")` is what you are looking for

Comment: I just want to put a new label in the place of old one when button is clicked

Comment: Your use of terminology is confusing us. The word "label" in this context refers to an actual widget object. It's unclear why you want to replace that widget object when it's more efficient to change the text on that object. It's unusual (though certainly not impossible) to replace the actual label widget, but it's an unusual request. We're just trying to understand what your requirements are.

Comment: @BryanOakley, I'm sorry I am new to Python I am ok to replace the text as well instead of replacing the label widget, My requirement is just to display the new text whenever a button is clicked.

Comment: @FSS So just use what I suggested earlier: `<your old label that you want to change>.config(text="<new text goes here>")`

Comment: @TheLizzard Thankyou, I have tried it but I am getting the error : label1 = Label.config(text="new line label").place(x=800, y=100)
TypeError: configure() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: @FSS Ok I see what happened. What is the name of you old label? If it is `Label` then you have to change. This happens because when you imported tkinter like this: `from tkinter import *` it defined the variable `Label`. Python gets confused as to which definition to use: the one imported from tkinter or the one you defined in your code.

Comment: It is Label1 is what I used

Comment: so use `Label1.config(text="<new text goes here>"`. I will write an answer because I think you are going to get an error

Answer (score 1):

This is how to change the text inside a `<tkinter.Label>`:

```py
import tkinter as tk


# When the user presses the button this function will be called
def callback():
    # Get the label that we defined
    global Label1

    # We are going to get its contents
    text = Label1.cget("text")

    # We are going to change the text
    new_text = text+"!"

    # We are going to insert back the text
    Label1.config(text=new_text)


# Create the window
root = tk.Tk()

# Create the label (we are going to change its contents later)
Label1 = tk.Label(root, text="Click the button bellow")
Label1.pack()
# Note I didn't do `tk.Label(rot, text="Click the button bellow").pack()` as I
# wouldn't be able to change the contents of the label later.

# Create the button
button = tk.Button(root, text="Click me", command=callback)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Read the comments carefully and tell me if you don't get what I have done.